# How to check the NVCC version with CMake 3.15?

Tags: cmake, build, cuda, nvcc

How does one check the version of NVCC, with CMake 3.15 (not 3.17 or later)?

I suppose I could write my own module to run it with `--version`, but is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CMake 3.15 with `CUDA` language support enabled, the `CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER_VERSION` variable is defined and contains the correct version. MRE:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(test LANGUAGES CUDA)

message(STATUS "CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER = ${CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER}")
message(STATUS "CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER_ID = ${CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER_ID}")
message(STATUS "CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER_VERSION = ${CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER_VERSION}")
```

Output:

```makefile
$ cmake-3.15 -S . -B build
-- The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 10.1.243
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/bin/nvcc
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/bin/nvcc -- works
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info - done
-- CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER = /usr/bin/nvcc
-- CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER_ID = NVIDIA
-- CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER_VERSION = 10.1.243
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/alex/test/build
```

I have various versions of CMake installed as `cmake-3.XX`, I assume you would simply run `cmake`.